I want to generate heatmaps from clip model (contrastive learning)
I tried so many times to generate heatmaps from clip model, this model is little different than standard clip model as i am using multi encoders and concat them before feeding it to clip model. However I have generated now some heatmaps and I am uploading their pictures.
When I run this code
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Assuming you have already trained the clip_model
# Create a new model for Grad-CAM generation
input_image = keras.Input(shape=(312, 312, 3))

global_activations = clip_model.global_vision_encoder(input_image)
local_activations = clip_model.local_vision_encoder(input_image)

# Create separate Grad-CAM models for impression and finding embeddings
impression_gradcam_model = keras.Model(
    inputs=[input_image, clip_model.impression_input],
    outputs=[global_activations, local_activations]
)

finding_gradcam_model = keras.Model(
    inputs=[input_image, clip_model.finding_input],
    outputs=[global_activations, local_activations]
)

# Function to preprocess the input image
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
    image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image, channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (312, 312))
    image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    return image

# Example usage
image_path = r"C:\Users\zahid\Desktop\3130_IM-1472-1001.dcm.png"
impression = "1.No acute cardiopulmonary findings."
finding = "No focal consolidation. No visualized pneumothorax. No large pleural effusions. The heart size and cardiomediastinal silhouette are grossly unremarkable"

# Load and resize the input image
input_image_resized = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_path), (312, 312))

def compute_gradcam(model, inputs, activations):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(inputs[0])
        _, local_activations = model(inputs)
        class_output = tf.reduce_mean(local_activations, axis=[0])
    grads = tape.gradient(class_output, inputs[0])
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=[0, 1, 2])
    pooled_grads = tf.expand_dims(pooled_grads, axis=-1)
    activations = tf.cast(activations, pooled_grads.dtype)  # Cast activations to the same data type as pooled_grads
    gradcam = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(activations, pooled_grads), axis=[0, 1])
    gradcam = tf.maximum(gradcam, 0)
    gradcam = (gradcam - tf.reduce_min(gradcam)) / (tf.reduce_max(gradcam) - tf.reduce_min(gradcam) + 1e-8)
    return gradcam

impression_inputs = [preprocess_image(image_path), tf.constant([impression], dtype=tf.string)]
_, impression_activations = impression_gradcam_model(impression_inputs)
impression_gradcam = compute_gradcam(impression_gradcam_model, impression_inputs, impression_activations)

finding_inputs = [preprocess_image(image_path), tf.constant([finding], dtype=tf.string)]
_, finding_activations = finding_gradcam_model(finding_inputs)
finding_gradcam = compute_gradcam(finding_gradcam_model, finding_inputs, finding_activations)

print("Impression Grad-CAM values:\n", impression_gradcam)
print("Finding Grad-CAM values:\n", finding_gradcam)

def normalize_gradcam(gradcam):
    gradcam_norm = (gradcam - tf.reduce_min(gradcam)) / (tf.reduce_max(gradcam) - tf.reduce_min(gradcam) + 1e-8)
    return gradcam_norm

impression_gradcam_norm = normalize_gradcam(impression_gradcam)
finding_gradcam_norm = normalize_gradcam(finding_gradcam)

print(f"Impression Grad-CAM heatmap values: min={tf.reduce_min(impression_gradcam_norm):.2f}, max={tf.reduce_max(impression_gradcam_norm):.2f}")
print(f"Finding Grad-CAM heatmap values: min={tf.reduce_min(finding_gradcam_norm):.2f}, max={tf.reduce_max(finding_gradcam_norm):.2f}")

def apply_colormap_and_overlay(gradcam_norm, input_image):
    gradcam_norm = tf.reshape(gradcam_norm, (1, 1))
    gradcam_norm_rgb = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.expand_dims(gradcam_norm, axis=-1))
    gradcam_norm_resized = tf.image.resize(gradcam_norm_rgb, (input_image.shape[0], input_image.shape[1]))
    gradcam_heatmap = np.uint8(255 * gradcam_norm_resized.numpy())
    gradcam_overlay = cv2.addWeighted(input_image, 0.8, gradcam_heatmap, 0.5, 0)
    return gradcam_overlay


impression_gradcam_overlay = apply_colormap_and_overlay(impression_gradcam_norm.numpy(), input_image_resized)
finding_gradcam_overlay = apply_colormap_and_overlay(finding_gradcam_norm.numpy(), input_image_resized)

# Display the results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(15, 5))

axes[0].imshow(input_image_resized)
axes[0].set_title("Input Image")

axes[1].imshow(impression_gradcam_overlay)
axes[1].set_title("Impression Grad-CAM Heatmap")

axes[2].imshow(finding_gradcam_overlay)
axes[2].set_title("Finding Grad-CAM Heatmap")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

It generates something like this without highlighting the regions like heatmap does.
I also printed some lines, it may help you understand the problem.
Impression Grad-CAM values:
 tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Finding Grad-CAM values:
 tf.Tensor(0.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
Impression Grad-CAM heatmap values: min=0.00, max=0.00
Finding Grad-CAM heatmap values: min=0.00, max=0.00


